# PlayerPrefs for score in dynamically loaded levels

Tags: unity-game-engine

Im creating a brick breaker game in Unity with one scene called Game that loads every single level based on data received from a json file.

I.E :

- Once all bricks are destroyed from 1 level, the second level is
  loaded in the same scene, and so on.
- Once you lose, a "Lose" scene is loaded with a "Play Again" button.

I'd like the high score information to be retained in the player prefs even after you press the "Play Again" button.

But I'm a bit confused to how this works. This is my code for score:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Score : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Text scoreText;
    public Text highScoreText;
    private int score;
    private int highScore;

    void Start()
    {
        score = 0;
        GetHighScore();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        UpdateScore();
        SetHighScore();
        GetHighScore();
    }

    // TO UPDATE HIGH SCORE
    void SetHighScore()
    {
        if (score > highScore)
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("HighScore", score);
        }
    }

    void GetHighScore()
    {
        highScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HighScore");
        highScoreText.text = "High score: " + highScore;
    }
    // TO UPDATE HIGH SCORE

    // TO UPDATE SCORE
    public void AddPoints(int points)
    {
        score = score + points;
        UpdateScore();
    }

    void UpdateScore()
    {
        scoreText.text = "score: " + score;
    }
    // TO UPDATE SCORE
}
```

So far the score updates fine, but nothing happens to the high score. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method here achives nothing

```
void GetHighScore()
{
    PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HighScore");
}
```

It should be

```
void GetHighScore()
{
    highScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HighScore");
}
```

And i dont see the point in calling it every frame in `Update`. Call it once in `Start`

Also, you may want to update `highScore` in `SetHighScore`

```
if (score > highScore)
{
    highScore = score;
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("HighScore", highScore);
    highScoreText.text = "high score: " + highScore;
}
```

Comment: wouldnt the last line be "highScoreText.text = "high score: " + highScore;
since highScore = score;

Comment: Well it doesnt matter really, since highScore has the same value as score :) But i agree it makes more sense when you read it

Comment: SO I've done this: 
// TO UPDATE HIGH SCORE
    void SetHighScore()
    {
        if (score > highScore)
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("HighScore", score);
        }
    }

    void GetHighScore()
    {
        highScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HighScore");
        highScoreText.text = "high score: " + highScore;
    }
    // TO UPDATE HIGH SCORE

Comment: @Frederik For some reason highscore still never changes

Comment: You mean the UI text doesnt update? Are you getting any errors in the Unity console?

Comment: Yeah the UI text doesn't update for high score. And no errors in the console!

Comment: I reproduced a sample with the same code and it seems to run fine here! Strange. Both texts are assiged to the script in the inspector?

Comment: So Score Script is assigned to an empty game object "Score", and within the Score script, both Score Text and High Score Text are assigned to their corresponding Text UI.

Comment: @Frederik I added Debug.Log("setHighScore"); inside the if of SetHighScore(); and it never prints to the console so for some reason there's a problem there. Just can't figure out what

Comment: Ok, so. It doesnt print inside the if-condition. Does it print outside the if-condition? Is the if-condition met? You could try a Debug.Log(score + " versus " + highScore); to get a better sense of what is happening perhaps

Comment: Wow. The high score text wasn't set to overflow so it was updating, I just wasn't seeing it. So stupid my bad. Thanks for your help! Made it correct answer